# Access Table column with String

Tags: julia

How can one pass the name of a table column to a function and access this column in the function? For example, if we define

```
using TypedTables
t = Table(time = [1,2,3], valueA = [10, 20, 30])
```

then I can simply access columns as follows

```
t.time
```

where I explicitly spell out the column name. However, what I want to do is pass the table and some column names to a function and access them within the function, the table columns

```
function fn(cnames::Array{String,1}, t::Table)
   for c in cnames
       #get column c from table t
       #do something with column c
   end
end
```

I don't know what to do in the for-loop. Simply putting

```
t.c
```

or

```
t.Symbol(c)
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you what you are looking for is `getproperty`:

```
julia> getproperty(t, :valueA)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 20
 30
```

`columns` also includes a tuple with all columns of the table so you could try as well:

```
julia> columns(t)[:valueA]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 20
 30
```

Actually looking at the package source code this is exactly how `getproperty` is defined so you are free to use either option:

```
@inline Base.getproperty(t::Table, name::Symbol) = getproperty(columns(t), name)
```

#### EDIT

if your column comes as a `String` cast it to a `Symbol`:

```
julia> getproperty(t, Symbol("valueA"))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 20
 30
```

Comment: Thanks! Kinda, but I think my main problem is that I'm given the column names as strings and I need to convert them to something that allows me to access the table column. So what I would need is something like `getproperty(t, "valueA")` resp. something like `columns(t)[:"valueA"]`.

Comment: Edited the answer and added a relevant comment