# Change variable name dynamically

Tags: julia

I have a dataframe with some columns,sometimes it can be : `[Type_House, Name, Location]`.

And sometimes it can be: `[Type_Build, Name, Location]`

There is a way to acess this dataframe column *Type* dynamically, like?

```
colName = "House"
dataframe.Type_colName
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74501256/3141234

Comment: I think I missed some details in my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Use `dataframe[!, colname]` instead of the dot fieldname notation.

Comment: @andrdpedro That's really no different, you're just prepending a prefix to the string before you use it to look something up.

Answer (score 2):

if you have

```
colName = "House"
```

you can access the column with

```
df[!, colName]
```

and from there you can use `typeof()` or `eltype()` to get the type or element type of that column

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @jling but specific to your question it would be:

```
> colName = "House"
> df[!, "Type_"*colName]
```

or

```
> getproperty(df, "Type_"*colName)
```

then you can just change `colName="Build"` to select the other column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the column that starts with *Type_*, you can use the `names` function this way:

```
julia> df = DataFrame( Type_Build = ["foo", "bar"], Name = ["A", "B"])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Type_Build  Name   
     │ String      String 
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ foo         A
   2 │ bar         B

julia> names(df, startswith("Type_"))
1-element Vector{String}:
 "Type_Build"
```

To access the values in the column, you can use that to index into the dataframe:

```
 julia> df[!, names(df, startswith("Type_"))]
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ Type_Build 
     │ String     
─────┼────────────
   1 │ foo
   2 │ bar
```